# Add an ISAPI Filter to an existing Site with Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5

I'm trying to add/configure an ISAPI Filter through c# and the Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly. So far I didn't manage to add an an ISAPI Filter for a single Web Site.

I just found [this Article (http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/isapiFilters)](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/isapiFilters) for adding it in the global setting for the whole IIS. I just need it for a specific site. I'm using IIS 7.5.

Comment: [Here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1149623.aspx) is a good thread from the IIS.net forums with source that shows how to do what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tweak the example given (see the inline comments):

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();   

Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

// Change this line:    
ConfigurationSection isapiFiltersSection = 
                           config.GetSection("system.webServer/isapiFilters");

// To this by adding an extra param specifying the site name:
ConfigurationSection isapiFiltersSection = 
              config.GetSection("system.webServer/isapiFilters", "my site name");


ConfigurationElementCollection isapiFiltersCollection = 
                           isapiFiltersSection.GetCollection();

ConfigurationElement filterElement = 
                        isapiFiltersCollection.CreateElement("filter");
filterElement["name"] = @"SalesQueryIsapi";
filterElement["path"] = @"c:\Inetpub\www.contoso.com\filters\SalesQueryIsapi.dll";
filterElement["enabled"] = true;
filterElement["enableCache"] = true;
isapiFiltersCollection.Add(filterElement);

serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

If you don't know the site name but know the site ID (or IIS number) then you can query the name by doing:

```
int iisNumber = 12345;
string siteName = serverManager.Sites.Single(s => s.Id == iisNumber).Name;
```