# Hosting an ISAPI DLL and supporting files in Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to find out how to host an ISAPI DLL in Azure. In addition to the DLL, I'll need to deploy supporting files in subdirectories (javascript & css files). And two of these subdirectories can have their contents changed by requests handled by the DLL, so I need to ensure that the account executing the extension has write permission for these.

It would seem that the key to all of this is using a startup task to call appcmd to script all the IIS changes somehow, and I think I need to do the following:-

- Deploy my ISAPI DLL and supporting files with my ASP.NET website
- Create a startup task which will call a batch file utilizing appcmd.exe to do the following:-

  - Create a dedicated app pool with its managed pipeline mode set to Classic, and using a known user account
  - Create an IIS application pointing to the directory where my ISAPI dll resides
  - Ensure the application is configured to allow unknown ISAPI extensions
  - Alter the permissions of the required subdirectories so the user account associated with the app pool has write access

I've only just started exploring Azure, so my experience with it is very thin on the ground. Is what I'm hoping to achieve actually achievable? And if so, am I on the right track with regards to the steps required? They mimic what I need to do if I'm setting up this ISAPI DLL in the traditional IIS environment I'm used to dealing with, but please let me know if the rules are different with Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good sequence, however, the startup tasks actually run before IIS is completely configured. The 'OnStart' event in the RoleEntryPoint is called after IIS is set up, so it's probably easier to use the IIS application that Azure creates for you, and reconfigure it to include your ISAPI stuff.

Comment: Yeah, it occurred to me after posting that it may be easier to utilise the existing ASP.NET application config as a basis. That may simplify things somewhat.

Comment: The IIS Administration pack adds a 'Configuration Editor' module, which makes it easy to modify the IIS configuration, and then save it as a script. It might save you some time. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/administration-pack

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the Administration pack to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well the only thing bothering me here is that you're modifying data on the 'deployment drive' (E: for that matter). You shouldn't be doing this.

Instead, think of an other solution. You could create a LocalResource holding your javascript and CSS files. Then, when your role starts (Richard has a valid point about startup tasks), use ServerManager class to do the following:

1. Register the [ISAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729879/add-an-isapi-filter-to-an-existing-site-with-microsoft-web-administration) dll
2. Add 2 virtual directories under the website created by Azure and point them to the LocalResource.
3. Modify the code of your ISAPI dll to modify JS/CSS files in the LocalResource

When developing in Web/WorkerRoles, you need to keep in mind that you should only manipulate files in a LocalResource.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'll look into them. As for modifying the ISAPI dll code, that may not be that easy. I use a third party framework which rewrites some of the javascript files on request. I'm not saying its impossible, but is something I'd leave as a last resort.